# JavaEE7 / JAX-RSで、遷移先のVIEWを表示できない

Tags: java, java-ee, jax-rs

最近のトレンドということで、
JavaEE7 / JAX-RSの勉強をしています。
適当にサンプルコードを拾い、いろいろ試しているんですが、
VIEWの表示がうまくできません。

現在参考にしているサイトは以下です。
http://masatoshitada.hatenadiary.jp/entry/2015/04/03/230218

今のところ、DB接続以前の問題なので、ビジネスロジック等は用意していません。

src/main/java/{package}/JaxrsActivator.java

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class JaxrsActivator extends Application{
}
```

src/main/java/{package}/Sample.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.mvc.Controller;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

@Path("")
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "sample")
public class Sample implements Serializable {

    private String myname;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        myname = "null";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("request")
    public String request(@QueryParam("name") String name) {
    myname = name;
    return "/request/index.html";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("top")
    public void hello() {
    }

    @GET
    @Path("")
    public String top() {
        return "top/index.html";
    }
}
```

src/main/webapp/top/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Start Page</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

src/main/webapp/request/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Start Page</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h:outputText id="myname" value="#{sample.myName}"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

上記ソースで、GlassFishを起動し、

localhost:8080/App/

に接続すると、

top/index.html

という文字列が表示されています。

localhost:8080/App/top

に接続すると、Internal Server Errorが、

localhost:8080/APP/requestに適当なGETリクエストを送っても結果は同じです。

どうすれば、VIEWを呼び出すことができるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaEE7にはそのような機能はないのではないですか？
JavaEE8からMVC的な機能があるようですが、JAVAEE7だとJSON／HTML／XMLの形式でしか返す機能は無いかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

参考にされているサイトの通りに設定できているのだとしたら、
「@Controller」アノテーションの付け忘れではないでしょうか？